# audio.play() not working when object is destroyed

Tags: c#, audio, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to play a sound when a `GameObject` is destroyed. However the sound won't play. I've tried it this way and by assigning the audio clip to a variable but neither seem to work. If I set the sound to play on awake it plays when the `GameObject` spawns, so I know the sound clip works - but it won't play when it is destroyed.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class DestroyByContact : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject explosion;
    public GameObject explosion02;
    public GameObject explosionShot;
    public int scoreValue;
    public GameController gameController;
    public int health;
    public AudioClip explosionSound01;

    void start () {
    }

    void Update () {
        if (health <= 0) {
            this.gameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource> ().Play ();
            Instantiate(explosion, transform.position, transform.rotation);
            Instantiate(explosion02, transform.position, transform.rotation);
            GameObject gc = GameObject.Find ("GameController");
            GameController gcs = gc.GetComponent<GameController> ();
            gcs.AddScore (scoreValue);
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }

        if (this.gameObject.tag == "Asteroid") {
            if (this.gameObject.transform.position.x  < -16) {
                Destroy (gameObject);
                Destroy (transform.parent.gameObject);
            }
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other){
        if (other.tag == "Boundary") {
            return;
        }
        if (other.tag == "Asteroid") {
            return;
        }
        if (other.tag == "Player") {
            Instantiate(explosion, transform.position, transform.rotation);
            Instantiate(explosion02, transform.position, transform.rotation);
            Destroy (gameObject);
        }
        if (other.tag == "Bullet") {
            Instantiate(explosionShot, transform.position, transform.rotation);
            other.gameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource> ().Play ();
            health -= 10;
            GameObject gc = GameObject.Find ("GameController");
            GameController gcs = gc.GetComponent<GameController> ();
            gcs.AddScore (10);
            Destroy (other.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cutting this down to the essential lines, we're left with just two:

```
this.gameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
Destroy(gameObject);
```

Destroying a GameObject will also destroy any components attached to it. You've told the `AudioSource` to play, and then immediately destroyed it. Once it has been destroyed, it no longer exists and therefore cannot play any sound.

To avoid this, you can create a separate GameObject to contain an `AudioSource` that will play the sound, then destroy that once it's finished.

Unity actually has a helper function, [`AudioSource.PlayOneShot`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.PlayOneShot.html), to do exactly that:

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(AudioSource))]
public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    public AudioClip impact;
    AudioSource audio;

    void Start() {
        audio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter() {
        audio.PlayOneShot(impact, 0.7F);
    }
}
```

If you need to have more control, you could create and manage your own GameObject, perhaps by [instantiating a prefab](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/InstantiatingPrefabs.html):

```
public class ExampleTwoClass : MonoBehaviour {
    public AudioSource audioPrefab;

    void OnCollisionEnter() {
        GameObject clone = Instantiate(audioPrefab, transform.position, transform.rotation) as GameObject;
        AudioSource cloneAudio = clone.GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        cloneAudio.play();

        //destroy clone once audio finishes
        Destroy(clone, cloneAudio.clip.length + 0.1f);
    }    
}
```

Comment: i tried doing it with your second method and got this error message: error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type `UnityEngine.Object' to `UnityEngine.GameObject'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?    any thoughts?

Comment: @MarkHughes88 Just add `as GameObject` to the end of the line instantiating the new copy. Try Googling your error next time before asking, as the very first search result is what you were looking for in this case. http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/41855/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-unityengineobject-t.html

Comment: ah yes my apologies. I ended up using your advise and just attached the audio clip to an empty game object, and instantiate that when the asteroid is destroyed. Worked a treat. I just had to set the new gameObject to destroy after 2f to remove it from the game hierarchy

Answer (score 1):

Well, the game object you're trying to play the sound *on* is being destroyed, so the audio source is going to be destroyed along with it.

You'll have to create an empty game object for the audio source to be attached to, placed at the destroyed object's position, and destroy that one after the sound effect finishes.  Or another, similar solution, depending on your exact needs (Destroy has a bit of overhead, so using a pooling system changes the answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can easily change your script to work, you just need to use Destroy(GameObject,float) method instead of Destroy(Gameobject).
This is  a handy solution.

```
if (health <= 0) {
            this.gameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource> ().Play ();
            Instantiate(explosion, transform.position, transform.rotation);
            Instantiate(explosion02, transform.position, transform.rotation);
            GameObject gc = GameObject.Find ("GameController");
            GameController gcs = gc.GetComponent<GameController> ();
            gcs.AddScore (scoreValue);
            Destroy(gameObject,1f);// here use time parameter.
        }
```

assign the the depends on your music's time if your exploit sound 1 sec then assign time Destroy(gameObject,1.25f).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this static method:

```
AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(soundClip, Camera.main.transform.position); 
Destroy(gameObject);
```

To set the sound clip from the inspector, add a member to the class:

```
[SerializeField]
private AudioClip soundClip;
```