# Sound not playing on last hit

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem which is that my hurt sound doesn't play on last hit. On other hits it works very well. I think that its because of the gameObject getting destroyed. I have tried it by putting the script to my bullet and changing the tag. Also the Debug.Log works perfectly on last hit. I hope that somebody could help me.

Anyway, here's my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class HealthSystem : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    public AudioSource source;
    
    public AudioClip clip;
    
    public Image healthBar;

    public float healthAmount = 100;

    public GameObject bullet;
    

    void Start()
    {

    }
    private void Update()
    {
        if(healthAmount <= 0)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }

    public void TakeDamage(float Damage)
    {
        source.PlayOneShot(clip);
        healthAmount -= Damage;
        healthBar.fillAmount = healthAmount / 100;
    }

    public void Healing(float healPoints)
    {
        healthAmount += healPoints;
        healthAmount = Mathf.Clamp(healthAmount, 0, 100);

        healthBar.fillAmount = healthAmount / 100;
    }
    
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.CompareTag("Bullet"))
        {
            if (!source.isPlaying)
            {
                Debug.Log("i have are played");
                TakeDamage(20);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if the `source` is part of the very same GameObject hierarchy that gets destroyed then yes that is probably the issue ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [audio.play() not working when object is destroyed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34092849/audio-play-not-working-when-object-is-destroyed)

Answer (score 1):

Exactly as you said: Because your game object is getting destroyed with last bullet, the `AudioSource` is getting destroyed with it and it cannot play whole sound. What is the workaround? There are 2, you can either:

- Spawn new `GameObject` just to play the sound and destroy it right after
- Hide/disable the object (as if it is destroyed), play the sound and once sample is played, destroy it